# Search and replace input placeholder text with jQuery

Tags: jquery, search, input, replace, placeholder

How can I search and replace placeholder text from all input boxes?

Example: I wanna change

```
<input type="text" name="user" id="user" placeholder="User">
```

to

```
<input type="text" name="user" id="user" placeholder="Benutzer">
```

By something like that

```
$('input').each(function() {
     $(this).attr("placeholder").replace('User', 'Benutzer');
});
```

Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Target elements based on the attribute, then change it

```
$('input[placeholder="User"]').attr('placeholder', 'Benutzer')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
    $('input').each(function(index, value) {
     $(this).attr('placeholder','Benutzer');
    });
```

Comment: No, this changes every input field placeholder to "Benutzer", but I only want to change those placeholders containing the string "User".